# Does there exist a nice closed form for multidimensional linear recurrence relations like those of single-dimensional ones?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

If we have the recurrence relation

$$\sum_{j=0}^k a_{n-j}c_j = 0$$

for all $n\geq k$ and $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_s$ are the (complex) roots of

$$P(\lambda) = \sum_{j=0}^k c_j\lambda^j$$

with multiplicities $m_1,\cdots,m_s$, then we may write

$$a_n = \sum_{i=1}^s \lambda_i^n Q_i(n),$$

where $Q_i(n)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m_i-1$.

What if we have a recurrence of the form

$$\sum_{\mathbf{s}\in S} c_{\mathbf{s}}a_{\mathbf{n}-\mathbf{s}} = 0,$$

where $S$ is a set of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^N$ and $\mathbf{n}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^N$ so that each component of $\mathbf{n}$ is $\geq$ the corresponding component of any $\mathbf{s}\in S$. Can one find a similarly nice closed form for $a_{\mathbf{n}}$, possibly using the zero set of

$$P(x_1,\cdots,x_N) = \sum_{\mathbf{s}\in S} c_{\mathbf{s}} \prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{\mathbf{s}_i}?$$

I've been able to deduce that the generating function

$$f(x_1,\cdots,x_N)  = \sum_{\mathbf{n}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^N} a_{\mathbf{n}}\prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{\mathbf{n}_i}$$

satisfies

$$f(x_1,\cdots,x_N)P(x_1,\cdots,x_N) = Q(x_1,\cdots,x_N)$$

for some polynomial $Q$ with nonzero terms only at $\prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{\mathbf{t}_i}$ for vectors $t$ that are $\leq$ some element of $S$ in all components, with strict $<$ holding in at least one component - an analogue of the first step of solving a standard one-dimensional linear recurrence. But I'm afraid I can't figure out how to continue from here, or even if one can.

Comment: you have described (by dividing out by leading coefficient) the Markov type process $x_{n+1} = M x_n$ with column vectors $x$ and square matrix $M.$ One may proceed by diagonalizing $P^{-1}MP$ and using revised vector..

Comment: I guess your $M$ has a special form as it also shifts the sequence by $1$

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for your comment! I can't quite understand why this is true, however. What are the entries of your $x_i$, and how are you constructing $M$ from the recurrence?

Comment: We can get the Fibonacci numbers with matrix $$ M = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)  $$ acting on column vector $$  \left( \begin{array}{c} x_{n+1}  \\ x_n \end{array}\right)  $$ to result in $$  \left( \begin{array}{c} x_{n+2}  \\ x_{n+1} \end{array}\right)  $$   For this method, the matrix $M$ will always come out to be a "companion matrix" or transpose, depends on how we make choices.

Comment: Then, the characteristic polynomial of this $M$ turns out to be $\lambda^2 - \lambda - 1$ which is exactly what we want.

Comment: Hmmm. I may have misunderstood entirely. I looked a bit more carefully at parts where you discuss the "multidimensional" aspect. Well, I won't delete these comments, they may help in some way.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks! I think that idea very well might be adaptable; even though $\mathbb{Z}^N$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic, I don't believe one can turn a recurrence of this form into a simple standard linear recurrence (although using any standard bijection) we can transform it into a single 1D sequence. There might be some better way to one-dimensionally represent such a recurrence, however.